# Which one of the following sets cannot be equal to $X$??

Tags: continuity

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $f,g:X \to X$ be continuous functions such that $f(X)\cap g(X)=\emptyset$ and $f(X)\cup g(X)=X$. Which one of the following sets cannot be equal to $X$?

A) $[0,1]$

B) $(0,1)$

C) $[0,1)$

D) $\mathbb{R}$

---

I don't know how I go through this problem. I think I have to choose some function to get the correct option but I can't. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is A) because then both $f[0,1]$ and $g[0,1]$ are compact and hence closed, and they are disjoint, nonempty, and $f[0,1]=[0,1]-g[0,1]$, so $f[0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$, so is $g[0,1]$, this shows that $[0,1]$ is disconnected, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand why you write $f[0,1]=[0,1]-g[0,1]$??

Comment: That is set difference. Because their union is the whole $[0,1]$ and they are disjoint. All I need is to show that they are open in $[0,1]$.

Comment: 0hhh thank you i understand .

Comment: But how you ensure that other option can be equal to X??

Comment: I didn't check all of those, but intuitively, say, $(0,1)$, $f(0,1)$ need not to be open or closed, so it seems that the connectedness of $(0,1)$ is not violated just by the images.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous image of an interval is again an interval (connectedness). The continuous image of a closed and bounded interval is a closed and bounded interval (compactness and connectedness).

Thus $X$ cannot be $[0,1]$, because there's no way to write $X$ as the disjoint union of two closed and bounded intervals: without loss of generality, you can assume that the maximum of $f(X)$ is less than the minimum of $g(X)$ and a contradiction is reached.

All other cases can happen. For instance, consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^2$, whereas $g(x)=-e^{-x}$. The cases B and C are similarly dealt with.